# sending PDF via JMS

Tags: java, pdf, jms

I need to send a PDF file via JMS.

Which message type shall I use?

```
public write(Document file){
  // I intentionally deleted some lines of code
  MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(adminQueue);

  BlobMessage bm=((org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession)session).createBlobMessage(file);
  producer.send(bm);
}
```

This solution didn't work.

createBlobMessage doesn't accept Document Type, it says "change type of 'file' to 'URL'" or "Change to createObjectMessage()"

I add that the pdf file is generated by itextpdf

Comment: CreateBlobMessage doesn't accept Document Type.

Comment: What steps have you taken to resolve the problem with the document type? Have you invested effort to understand precisely what the error is about?

Comment: First i need to cast the document to something that i can send via JMS, so i tried with ObjectMessage and BytesMessage and BlobMessage. it says it cannot be cast to ..         I add that the document was generated by itextpdf.

Comment: Apparently, your `file` is of type `Document`, which is a type from your PDF-building API. It makes little sense to try to send that object over the wire. You want to send the PDF file itself, so build the file first.

Comment: how?
by converting it?by FileInputStream?

Comment: I am not an expert on iText, but this is what stands in the Javadoc: `PdfWriter.getInstance(document , new FileOutputStream("text.pdf"));`